# Tag helpers not working with DynamicRouteValueTransformer

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

ASP.NET Core's [tag helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1) appear not to be working in combination with [DynamicRouteValueTransformer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.dynamicroutevaluetransformer?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Here's an MCVE: let's say we have a simple controller with two actions...

```
public class GenericController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Add()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

... and the `Index` view links to the `Add` action with the `asp-action` tag helper:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <a asp-action="Add">Add new!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When we now open `/Generic` in a browser and inspect the page, we'll notice that ASP.NET generated the expected `href` value for the controller action:

```
<a href="/Generic/Add">Add new!</a>
```

So far, so good. Now let's create a `DynamicRouteValueTransformer` which routes all requests to that same controller...

```
    public class Transformer : DynamicRouteValueTransformer
    {
        public override ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
        {
            if (values.ContainsKey("controller"))
            {
                values["originalController"] = values["controller"];
                values["controller"] = "Generic";
            }
            return new ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary>(values);
        }
    }
```

... and let's set it up for endpoint routing in `Startup.cs`...

```
            services.AddSingleton<Transformer>();
...
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<Transformer>("{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

After opening `/Generic` (or any other route, e.g. `/Foobar`) in a browser and inspecting the page, we'll now notice that `asp-action` tag helper is no longer working:

```
<a href="">Add new!</a>
```

Since the href value is empty, the link is no longer working. It looks the dynamic routing broke the tag helper.

Any suggested fix or workaround?

Comment: Can reproduce the issue within my app, and find same issue reported on github issue:https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16965 We can trace updates of this issue.

Comment: Thanks! So it's really an ASP.NET bug, wow. I thought I was missing something.